# When using jQuery's .ajax, what word do you use to refer to the data retrieved?

Tags: jquery, ajax

For example lets say that the data retrieved was integer 2 and we wanted to assign this value to variable 'num', using the following code:

```
$.ajax({
url: "index.php",
dataType: "JSON",
success: function(){
    var num = ???;
    }
})
```

What would you type in place of '???' ?

Comment: `data` for the callback argument then whatever property name the value is assigned to on `data` (as the response is JSON). It's data so data is not a bad name for it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response is passed as an argument to the callback.  Simply define an argument:

```
success: function(response){
    // "response" contains the response from the server
}
```

You can, of course, call the variable anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

To give another example with a little more detail:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    dataType: "JSON", //dataType only modifies what is coming BACK from PHP side
    success: function(recd){
        //if (recd.length > 0) alert(recd);
        var num = recd.number; //or whatever that variable is called in the JSON
    }
});
```